# JW Player Gem is not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jwplayer

I have installed jwplayer gem and tried the following in the view page.

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>

 <%= video_player({:file => "/home/user/Downloads/digital.mp4", :image => "/home/user/Downloads/Retreats_21.jpg"}) %>
```

But its throwing error message like "Get the Adobe Flash Player to see this video". But i have already installed the adobe flash player. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962883

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you haven't installed jwplayer_rails gem and you installed only gem 'jw_player_helper'. So Please install the gem and try once again.

```
 gem 'jwplayer-rails'
```